# I am getting a segmentation fault rather than printing the struct value

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a record in which I can keep track of students' names and their scores. After running, I enter one student record and after entering two records, I am getting a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) error.

I don't understand what is causing this error as I am a beginner to the C language.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Students {
    char name[100];
    int roll;
    float mark;
} Student;


int main() {
    int N, i;
    printf("How many students do you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%i", &N);
    Student *st = malloc(N*sizeof(Student));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", st[i].name);
        st[i].roll = i;
        printf("Enter score for %s", st[i].name);
        scanf("%f", &st[i].mark);
        printf("%i. %s ", i, st[i].name);
        printf("%s: %f ", i, &st[i].mark);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn warnings on;  I'm sure you'll see lots.   Off the cuff, you're passing an integer for some of your format string that takes a %s on that last printf().

Comment: A few more observations with your code

You have a %s format identifier for an integer, whereas %s expects a pointer to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have an explanation for where you *segfault* originated, if you are going to learn C, do not learn bad habits early. There are a number of issues you should address before you consider your code reliable, and a number of others you can address to make your code work like it appears you intended.

First and foremost, *validate* ***all*** *user input!*. If you fail to validate all user input you have no idea if your code is processing garbage or straying off into *undefined behavior* from the first input you take. A user can input anything—or a cat can walk on the keyboard, etc... It is your responsibility to verify you have the input you are expecting.

For example, from your very first input, you should, *at minimum* check the return of `scanf` to insure you have the number of *successful conversions* you expect. It is simple to do, e.g.,

```
if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1) {    /* validate number */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (number).\n");
    return 1;
}
```

When taking string input you need to limit the number of characters you accept to the size of the storage available. You can accomplish this with `scanf` using the *width* modifier. Since you have *100* characters available in `name`, you can store *99 characters* plus the *null-terminating byte*. Additionally, since names can contain whitespace, you can use a *character class* to read all characters up to the `'\n'` character. (here you are better served using *line-oriented* input functions such as `fgets`). E.g.,

```
    if (scanf (" %99[^\n]%*c", st[i].name) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (name).\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

You also need to understand you are leaving the `'\n'` in the *input buffer* (`stdin`) and you must account for that if your next input is character input of `scanf` will happily take the `'\n'` as your input. All line oriented input functions (`fgets`, `getline`) read and include the `'\n'`, `scanf` does not. You can however use the *assignment suppression* operator `'*'` to *read-and-discard* the specified input (`%*c` to read/discard the next character (the `'\n'`)).

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have two *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. E.g.,

```
free (st);  /* free allocated memory */
```

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory, attempted to read or base a jump on an uninitialized value and finally to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated. For Linux, [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) is the normal choice, but there are similar programs for each OS.

Last, while not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids `caMelCase` variables in favor of all *lower-case*. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf)

Putting all of that together, and tweaking the output and formatting to what it seems you intended (I could be totally wrong), you could rewrite you code something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct students {
    char name[100];
    int roll;
    float mark;
} student;

int main ()
{
    int n = 0, i = 0, maxc = 0; /* initialize variables */
    student *st = NULL;

    printf ("How many students do you want to enter: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1) {    /* validate number */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (number).\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* allocate & validate */
    if ((st = malloc (n * sizeof (student))) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {       /* take input & validate */
        printf ("enter name: ");    /* limit & accept full name */
        if (scanf (" %99[^\n]%*c", st[i].name) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (name).\n");
            return 1;
        }
        st[i].roll = i;

        printf ("enter score for %s: ", st[i].name);
        if (scanf ("%f", &st[i].mark) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (mark).\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* compute max length for name */
        int len = (int)strlen (st[i].name);
        if (len > maxc)
            maxc = len;
    }

    printf ("\nroll  %-*s  mark\n\n", maxc, "name");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" %3d  %-*s  %.2f\n",
                st[i].roll, maxc, st[i].name, st[i].mark);

    free (st);  /* free allocated memory */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/structloop
How many students do you want to enter: 4
enter name: John J. Franklin
enter score for John J. Franklin: 83.1
enter name: Betty C. Smith
enter score for Betty C. Smith: 91.2
enter name: Jennifer L. Burgen-Kwiatkowski
enter score for Jennifer L. Burgen-Kwiatkowski: 88.7
enter name: Alfred R. Murrow
enter score for Alfred R. Murrow: 73.5

roll  name                            mark

   0  John J. Franklin                83.10
   1  Betty C. Smith                  91.20
   2  Jennifer L. Burgen-Kwiatkowski  88.70
   3  Alfred R. Murrow                73.50
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "the standard coding style for C". Making such claims and basing them on a more than 20-year-old document from a single organization is dangerous. Even the *C language standard* has changed quite considerably since that time. Any coding standard should make the code and its intent clear, and is an agreement between users. `idonotwantoreadcodelikethisbutothersmight`. For more modern language agnostic coding practices, search for Robert C. Martin's Clean Code available as a book and an online video series. Otherwise, a very educational answer here.

Comment: I disagree, having worked, in part, on the development of it at NASA.

Comment: I think you missed my point. Style guides and coding guidelines are invaluable in any organization. I work primarily with MISRA-C:2012 and we have an additional in-house style guide. While adhering to both is mandatory, neither of them claims to be a de facto or de jure standard for the language. The same is true for the NASA guide. It is the standard practice for NASA, but does not claim to be *the universal standard*. That is the the distinction I wished to make to avoid confusing a novice reader. And a 1994 guide for a C99/C11 programmer can only be a general guide.

Comment: No, I understood you perfectly. You misrepresent my statement and then argue its *"dangerous"*. I merely made the recommendation that C avoids `camelCase` in favor of *lower-case* and then offered, as an example, the programming style manual that provides support. **note** the appropriate *signal* `See e.g.`. Was the point in attacking that proposition, to say `camelCase` is recommended in C? No, I don't believe so. I welcome any point you have to make, but do so in a diplomatic manner, otherwise, it's just trolling.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for your help. I took your suggestion and rewrote my code as you had suggested and it works. I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 2):

Using a debugger and backtracking at the core dump, you get that it crashes here;

```
printf("%s: %f ",i,&st[i].mark);
```

The line should probably look something like this instead;

```
printf("%d: %f ",i,st[i].mark);
```